# Biblatex change last visited

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I need to change the text from "last visited" to "visited at" and without brackets? How do I do that?

```
\begin{filecontents}{\test.bib}
@online{gates,
    author       = {Bill Gates}
    title        = {Save the world!
    url          = {https://www.gatesfoundation.org/de/},
    date         = {2016-07-04},
    organization = {Bill and Melinda Gates Foundation}
}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authortitle]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\test.bib}
\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.\footcite{gates}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your given bib entry are some coma missing and there is a wrong `}`.  See the following MWE for the correct entry.

You can use `\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{visted at #1}` to change the printed urldate. Please see that you have to use `urldate` instead `url`.

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@online{gates,
    author       = {Bill Gates},
    title        = {Save the world!},
    url          = {https://www.gatesfoundation.org/de/},
    urldate      = {2016-07-04},
    organization = {Bill and Melinda Gates Foundation},
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authortitle]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{visted at #1}


\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.\footcite{gates} \cite{gates}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

As mentioned by @moewe in his comment the best solution for your issue is the following:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@online{gates,
    author       = {Bill Gates},
    title        = {Save the world!},
    url          = {https://www.gatesfoundation.org/de/},
    urldate      = {2016-07-04},
    organization = {Bill and Melinda Gates Foundation},
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authortitle]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{% <==================================
  urlseen = {visited at}            % <==================================
}
\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{\bibstring{urlseen}\space#1} % <============


\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.\footcite{gates} \cite{gates} \citeurl{gates}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please note that usually an approach using bibstrings (such as in Guido's answer) is infinitely preferable to hard-coded strings, especially if a suitable bibstring is readily available.

Answer (score 6):

You can customise the text for `urlseen` bibliography string, using something like

```
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{
  urlseen = {visited on} 
}
```

See Sections 3.9 and 4.9 of the biblatex manual.

To remove the parenthesis use

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{\bibstring{urlseen}\space#1}
```