# Changing Bibliography Strings only for Certain References

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

The answers to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/464198/biblatex-change-last-visited) explain how `\DefineBibliographyStrings` can be used to change the "last visted" text for `@online` citations.

However, this solution changes the text for all references of this type. I would like to be able to change the text only for certain references.

I have some references to current webpages which I would like to keep as "last visited", however I also have some links to archive.org where I would like this to instead be displayed as "archived on".

Here is a MRE, and the output. I would like the stack exchange reference to prefix the date with "archived on", but the wikipedia reference to remain as the default "visited at".

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{citations.bib}
@online{wikipedia,
    author       = {{Wikimedia Foundation}},
    title        = {Wikipedia},
    url          = {https://en.wikipedia.org},
    year         = {2019},
    urldate      = {2019-12-09}
}
@online{stack,
    author       = {{Stack Exchange Inc}},
    title        = {Stack Overflow},
    url          = {https://web.archive.org/web/20100813082822/http://www.stackoverflow.com/},
    year         = {2010},
    urldate      = {2010-08-13}
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,backend=bibtex,urldate=long]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{citations.bib}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{
  urlseen = {archived on} 
}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet \autocite{wikipedia}, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua \autocite{stack}. 
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: references]

Comment: You might be able to modify this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/265929/108704

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a straightforward adaptation of [moewe's answer to "Custom bib style for entries containing editor"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/265929/108704) (if this works for you, go upvote it too!).

First, add the following code to your preamble. This will make biblatex write "archived on" for references which include `options = {archived}`, and the default string otherwise.

```
% define a new "archivedon" string as an alternative to "urlseen"
\NewBibliographyString{archivedon}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{ 
    archivedon = {archived on}
}

% for each reference, detect if the "archived" option is used and set the urldate string accordingly
\newtoggle{bib:archived}
\DeclareEntryOption{archived}[true]{%
  \settoggle{bib:archived}{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{% 
  \mkbibparens{%
    \iftoggle{bib:archived}
      {\bibstring{archivedon}} % "archived" option is on - write "archived on"
      {\bibstring{urlseen}} % "archived" option is off - write "visited on"
    \addcolon\space#1}}
```

Then you have one or two options, depending on what bibliography backend (bibtex or biber) you use:

a) If you use bibtex or don't want to automate this part, you'll need to edit your .bib file and add `options = {archived}` to all the references where you want to use "archived on":

```
@online{stack,
    author  = {{Stack Exchange Inc}},
    title   = {Stack Overflow},
    url     = {https://web.archive.org/web/20100813082822/http://www.stackoverflow.com/},
    year    = {2010},
    urldate = {2010-08-13},
    options = {archived}
}
```

b) If you use biber, you don't need to edit the .bib file, as it can set the `archived` option automatically (this doesn't work with bibtex):

```
% automatically add the "archived" option when reference url contains "archive.org"
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map[overwrite]{
      \step[fieldsource=url, match=\regexp{archive\.org},final] 
      \step[fieldset=options, append, fieldvalue={archived=true}] 
    }
  }
}
```

---

MWE for bibtex (requires editing your .bib file to add the `archived` option to archive.org references):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{citations.bib}
@online{wikipedia,
    author       = {{Wikimedia Foundation}},
    title        = {Wikipedia},
    url          = {https://en.wikipedia.org},
    year         = {2019},
    urldate      = {2019-12-09}
}
@online{stack,
    author       = {{Stack Exchange Inc}},
    title        = {Stack Overflow},
    url          = {https://web.archive.org/web/20100813082822/http://www.stackoverflow.com/},
    year         = {2010},
    urldate      = {2010-08-13},
    options      = {archived}
}

\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,backend=bibtex,urldate=long]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{citations.bib}


% use "archived on" instead of "visited on" when bib entry includes "options = {archived}"
%   (inspired by https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/265929)
\NewBibliographyString{archivedon}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{ 
    archivedon = {archived on} 
}
\newtoggle{bib:archived}
\DeclareEntryOption{archived}[true]{%
  \settoggle{bib:archived}{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{%
  \mkbibparens{%
    \iftoggle{bib:archived}
      {\bibstring{archivedon}}
      {\bibstring{urlseen}}%
    \addcolon\space#1}}
%-----


\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet \autocite{wikipedia}, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua \autocite{stack}. 

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

---

MWE for biber (automatic, no .bib edits needed):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{citations.bib}
@online{wikipedia,
    author       = {{Wikimedia Foundation}},
    title        = {Wikipedia},
    url          = {https://en.wikipedia.org},
    year         = {2019},
    urldate      = {2019-12-09}
}
@online{stack,
    author       = {{Stack Exchange Inc}},
    title        = {Stack Overflow},
    url          = {https://web.archive.org/web/20100813082822/http://www.stackoverflow.com/},
    year         = {2010},
    urldate      = {2010-08-13}
}

\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,backend=biber,urldate=long]{biblatex} % changed to biber
\addbibresource{citations.bib}


% use "archived on" instead of "visited on" when bib entry includes "options = {archived}"
%   (inspired by https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/265929)
\NewBibliographyString{archivedon}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{ 
    archivedon = {archived on} 
}
\newtoggle{bib:archived}
\DeclareEntryOption{archived}[true]{%
  \settoggle{bib:archived}{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{%
  \mkbibparens{%
    \iftoggle{bib:archived}
      {\bibstring{archivedon}}
      {\bibstring{urlseen}}%
    \addcolon\space#1}}
%----------

% for biber only - add the "archived" option automatically when url contains "archive.org"
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map[overwrite]{
      \step[fieldsource=url, match=\regexp{archive\.org},final]
      \step[fieldset=options, append, fieldvalue={archived=true}]
    }
  }
}
%-----


\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet \autocite{wikipedia}, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua \autocite{stack}. 

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Side note: thanks for asking this question, @JShorthouse! You've inspired me to use this in my own documents.

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks very much for taking the time to adapt the other answer into something I could easily copy and paste!